# Why are two transitive actions of a group G equivalent if there exist an automorphism of G swapping two point stabilisers?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, group-actions

Let $G$ be a group acting transitively on two sets $\Omega_{1}$ and $\Omega_{2}$. Also let $w_{i}\in\Omega_{i}$ and suppose there exists $\alpha\in Aut(G)$ such that $\alpha(G_{w_{1}})=G_{w_{2}}$, where $G_{w_{i}}$ denotes the point stabiliser of $w_{i}$. I would like to show that in this case the two actions of $G$ are equivalent, i.e. there exists a bijection $\phi: \Omega_{1} \to \Omega_{2}$ such that 
$$\phi(g(w_{1}))=\alpha(g)(\phi(w_{1})).$$

I'm not sure how to construct $\phi$ to start with.

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: You won't be able to show this, because it is not true! For example, $S_6$ has an outer automorphism that maps the natural representation of $S_6$ to an inequivalent representation.

Comment: Thanks! In the counter example you mentioned, is it possible to describe the inequivalent representation?

Comment: In the inequivalent representation a transposition like $(1,2)$ is mapped to a product of three transpositions like $(1, 6)(2, 3)(4, 5)$., and a $3$-cycle like $(1,2,3)$ is mapped to a product of two like $(1, 3, 5)(2, 6, 4)$.